# Typescript: Member of union type with incompatible signature when using find on array of objects

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript

I want to check if a value exists in an array of objects.

My array looks something like this:

```
[
 0: {
  id: 'unique_obj_id',
  item: {
   id: 'unique_item_id',
   ...
  },
  ...
 },
 1: {...}
]
```

The objects in the array can be one of many interface types (depending on my api call, here: `resource` strings represent these interfaces, which are defined somewhere else). But one array will always consist of the same interface types for a given data request.

I'm trying to write a reusable function to check whether `given_id` exists for any object in the array for `obj.item.id`.

So far I've managed to write the correct logic but typescript throws some exceptions that I can't seem to figure out. `shopApprovalData` is a collection of interfaces each following the above object structure accessible by the indices of `resource`.

```
export type ApprovalResource = 'str1' | 'str2' | 'str3' | 'str4' | 'str5';

export const checkApprovalItem = (given_id: string, resource: ApprovalResource) => {
  const shopApprovalData = useShopApprovals();

  if (shopApprovalData && shopApprovalData[resource]) {
    const resourceApprovalData = shopApprovalData[resource];
      if (resourceApprovalData.find(e => e.item.id === id)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Typescript shows me that `shopApprovalData` and `itemApprovalData` is possibly undefined and that the expression `find()` is not callable since signatures of members of the union type are not compatible with each other. (Apparently, [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) removes the error, why?)

What approach should I choose instead to check whether the `given_id` exists in any object of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your usecase, i create this code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-answer-ke9drk?file=/src/index.ts

explanation:

- `Type` wont compile, so we need something to mark what the interface of the object.

Also i may confused by your code `shopApprovalData[resource]` what do you want to achieve here? for example, if `resource` is `str1` `shopApprovalData[resource]` will always return `undefined` because no index `str1` in Array

I hope it help,
Best Regards

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't make it clear enough. The `str1` options represent the keys of the `shopApprovalData` interface. Each key of this interface then again is assigned an interface that is described by the array of objects above.

Comment: Edited the data array in your sandbox.

Comment: oh, please share your sandbox link, i don't see any change on my link

Comment: my bad, there you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-gwen-o2ou7e?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-answer-ke9drk?file=/src/index.ts

here the next version

Comment: So I've tried implementing your suggestion, but it breaks due to my webpack config (missing polyfills) I'd prefer a solution without external modules

Comment: sure, i will update the sandbox

Comment: @digitalsuite.net check again

Comment: @digitalsuite.net hello, is it solve your problem yet?